# Why can't the name of a `totcounter` be defined with a variable

Tags: counters, expansion, loops, totcount

I want to print the sum of some counter per subject at the beginning of that subject and I want it to be done automatically.

I decided to use the `totcount`-package. I then define a counter like:
`\newtotcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}`, where `subject` is another counter.

The strange thing is, this does succesfully define the counter `pointsInSubjectA` for instance, but I cannot call on `\total{pointsInSubjectA}`. (I haven't even tried yet to call `\total{\pointsInSubjec\Alph{subject}}`.)

Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}         \parindent=0pt

\newtotcounter{subject}
\def\subject{%
    \refstepcounter{subject}%
    \newtotcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}} \setcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}{0}
    Subject \thesubject\hfill\\}

\def\point#1{%
    Subsubject (#1 points)%
    \addtocounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}{#1}%
    }

\begin{document}
There are a total of \total{subject} subjects.

\bigskip
\subject This subject has a total of \total{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}} points\\
\point3\\ 
\point4\\
Now \texttt{\textbackslash thepointsInSubjectA}=\expandafter\csname thepointsInSubject\Alph{subject}\endcsname

\bigskip
\subject lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

It gives the following output:
[image]

How come the counter is defined but I cannot use `\total`?

Comment: At a guess, `\total` is not expanding `\Alph{subject}` correctly, and so can't figure out what you're asking it to print.  Expansion is tricky business in TeX, so you might be better off using your own definition in the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following modified version of the `\subject` command works:

```
\def\subject{%
    \refstepcounter{subject}%
    \edef\ptscountername{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}%
    \expandafter\newtotcounter\expandafter{\ptscountername}%
    \setcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}{0}%
    Subject \thesubject\hfill\\}
```

The reason: the way that the package `totcount` works is that for each new "totcounter" it creates an auxiliary counter called

```
<countername>@totc
```

and at the END of the document it writes to the `.aux` file the final value of `<countername>` into that variable. However, the code does **not** expand `<countername>` at the point of definition.

This means that when you called

```
\newtotcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}
```

the new counter that it created has name

```
pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}@totc
```

and not

```
pointsInSubjectA@totc
```

at first invocation. Now fast forward to the end of file, where `subject` now equals 2. When the code writes to the `.aux` file the final values, it expands `pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}@totc` **at that point** and since `subject` is equal to 2, the `.aux` file **only** records (twice) the total count for `pointsInSubjectB@totc` and never `pointsInSubjectA@totc`.

To work around this, you need to make sure that the auxilliary counter created by the package has the correct name; and to do so you need to make sure that the counter name is properly expanded before you feed it to `\newtotcounter`. There are different ways to do that, one way is to `\edef` a new command storing the full countername and force it to be expanded first via `\ea` when putting it into `\newtotcounter`, which is what I did above.

As egreg pointed out below, a better method for [up-to-date TeX distributions](https://www.texdev.net/2018/12/06/a-new-primitive-expanded) is replace the two lines starting with `\edef...` and `\expandafter...` with the single invocation

```
\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}}
```

Comment: It may be worth raising this with the package author, since I don't see any benefit to *not* expanding the counter name at the point of definition.

Comment: This is a real elegant and simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: Know a way to draw the attention of who's maintaining the package?

Comment: @gebruiker: go to CTAN, look up the `totcount` package, and open the documentation. Usually the package maintainer list his or her email on the first page of the doc. Email that person.

Comment: You can avoid the scratch macro with `\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\newtotcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{\subject}}}\x` or, with a recent TeX distribution, `\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}}`

Comment: @egreg: wow, that's a super-useful; did not know about this new primitive. Is there a difference between what you wrote versus `\expandafter\newtotcounter\expandafter{\expanded{pointsInSubject\Alph{subject}}}` (besides a lot more typing in my version)?

Comment: @WillieWong  No difference in the final result